# Include files for MASM x64

Tags: windows, assembly, visual-studio-2019, x86-64, masm

I am new to programming windows MASM applications and from what I understand in order to call WinAPI functions I need to first include the appropriate .inc files.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and I can't find anywhere on my system windows.inc files what so ever. I've

searched online and I couldn't find any SDK for x64 MASM.

This question was asked a while [ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915222/include-files-for-masm) but the answer is only relevant for x32 assembly.

Comment: *"from what I understand in order to call WinAPI functions I need to first include the appropriate .inc files"* - No, that is not a requirement. You need to make the function names visible to the assembler, and let the linker know which imports to resolve. The .inc files do that, but they don't do anything you couldn't be doing yourself. If you want to learn assembly, start by learning your tools (that's actually true for any programming language).

Comment: @IInspectable: Ok, to be fair, you could say the same thing about C and `stdio.h` for example.  Sure you *could* prototype all the functions yourself, but nobody would recommend that even though most of the prototypes are guaranteed by the C standard.  Also fair that it's good to understand that you *could* do that, especially for asm where normally you have to manage the calling convention yourself, though.

Comment: And IIRC, MASM might not support it's `invoke` directive or macro for x64.  If that's true, maybe there aren't `.inc` files at all, and you just have to `extern CreateFileA` and `call CreateFileA` or whatever after reserving shadow space and putting args in registers.

Comment: @pet `stdio.h` contains *implementations*. That's a fair bit different from the .inc files that only contain **declarations**. Declaring the symbols you need is - arguably - doable. Implementing (part of) the CRT, on the other hand, is far more involved. Not really and apples to apples analogy there. The main point being that it's far more important to understand the tools than to chase down the recommended way of doing things, without understanding what they do, or why that is recommended.

Comment: @IInspectable: Ok fine, how about `#include <unistd.h>` or `<sys/stat.h>`.  Those are just prototypes and struct layouts, not macros like `putchar` might be.  I was really just talking about function prototypes, which is actually a *good* analogy: compiling a C89 program like `int main(){puts("hello world");}` works without `#include<stdio.h>` via implicit declaration, but will warn with `gcc -std=c99`, and refuse to compile with C++ because of the missing prototype.  https://godbolt.org/z/vTbYobqzK

Comment: @pet Still a pretty poor analogy. If you are learning assembly, you certainly aren't doing so because it boosts your productivity. You do it purely for the educational aspect. Declaring your imports certainly is educational. Irrespective of that, I was commenting on a statement that is inarguably wrong, not on what is the recommended way of writing assembly applications.

Comment: @IInspectable can you recommend on any source that explains how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've been doing some digging and from what I understand there's no official SDK for x64 MASM which is weird. What I did find is this forum ["The MASM Forum"](http://masm32.com/board/index.php). And they are working on [x64 MASM SDK](http://masm32.com/board/index.php?board=53.0) for a while now but it has a lot of features.

They state it's not perfect but it's more than nothing.
I had trouble installing it to be honest, also my anti virus classified 2 of the files as Trojan so you should **download the files at your own risk**(Maybe do it on a VM ?).

Also the comments under the question suggested creating your own .inc files which from what I understand now is not that difficult, I will be trying both methods and keep this post updated on the results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're still wanting an answer, probably not since this was asked almost a year ago, but I'll reply to help anyone who may also be wondering. I just started trying to learn MASM and I was having a lot of trouble setting everything up, in fact I'm still working on getting x86 to work correctly on an USB (I think masm32 must be at the root of the USB(note: for old version, updated version will be more like x64))

**For x64 you'll need Visual Studio installed**, I'm using VS 2022. My examples should give you a good idea, just change to match your specific set up.

**ml64.exe**, **link.exe**, and **lib.exe** are all in the **same folder**:

```
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\Hostx64\x64\ml64.exe
```

The resource compiler, **rc.exe**, is in a **different folder**:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\rc.exe
```